# Postgres - Number of well supported objects

Tags: postgresql

Our postgres DBs have ~3million objects at the moment, of which ~2million are indexes, ~500k are tables and partitions and ~500k are toast tables. The number of objects increases by ~1million per year due to the creation of additional table partitions plus their indexes etc.

To me it seems ~3million objects are well within the theoretical limits, but definitely more than usual.

We are seeing (minor) problems because of having so many objects, but nothing breaking:

- Vacuum of an empty or non-exisiting table takes over 3 seconds
- Many wraparound-prevention vacuums
- Some queries against system tables take long, which makes tools like DBeaver crash sometimes
- Connections use more RAM for caching histograms etc. for the many objects/partitions
- Upgrades to higher postgres versions sometimes require additional work such as dropping many indexes and recreating them after the upgrade so that the upgrade finishes in an OK time

I have tested locally with up to 5 million objects.

My question is: Should we urgently start to implement changes to stabilize the number of objects? I see no real need at the moment. Postgres seems to deal just fine with that many partitions apart from the minor issues mentioned above. **Are there major issues ahead that will hit us at 5,6,7,10,20,50 million objects?**

Comment: This is probably a better question for the postgresql mailing lists where you can discuss your setup with the actual developers. https://www.postgresql.org/list/

Comment: @TheImpaler million - I have edited it for you

Comment: Half a million tables is not usual in a database model. What's the reason for having so many tables? Is this an OLAP model, or maybe you have tables "per user" or "per day"? Please elaborate.

Comment: Most objects come from table partitions + their indexes. We have about 80 partitioned tables, that are partitioned on a monthly (sometimes weekly) basis, whereas different customers do not share partitions. Rough calculation would be: 80 tables * 100 customers * 5 years * 12 months = 480.000 partitions

Comment: I would ask this question at dba.stackexchange.com. This falls into the admin side of databases, rather than into the programming side of them.

Comment: Why so many partitions? With a proper query, different users will never see data of other users. A single partition can usually hold hundreds of GB's of data. With 50GB each, this could be over 23000 TB. How big is your database?

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: @jjanes 14.5 - KR Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no principal limit of the number of tables, and there is also no limit of 65000 objects for a single query (I just tried with a table with 66000 partitions).

However, as you progress into these regions that PostgreSQL was never designed for, you start to notice that certain things become slow and painful. There is no hard limit, it will just keep hurting more and more.

I think that it would be a very good idea to redesign your application so that it uses a reasonable number of tables.

Comment: TY! I removed the 65k partitions in one explain plan part.